# Simple Schema populate default value from collection

Tags: simple-schema

How is it possible to populate simple schema's default value with a call to a collection in Meteor js instead of defining the "tests" within the defaultValue as below? If possible to have the defaultValue return all from TestList = new Mongo.Collection('testList').

```
StudentSchema = new SimpleSchema({

tests: {
type: [Object],
blackbox: true,
optional: true,

defaultValue:[
    {
        "_id" : "T2yfqWJ3a5rQz64WN",
        "category_id" : "5",
        "active" : "true",
        "category" : "Cognitive/Intelligence",
        "abbr" : "WJ-IV COG",
        "name" : "Woodcock-Johnson IV, Tests of Cognitive Abilities",
        "publisher" : "Riverside Publishing"
    },


    {
        "_id" : "Ai8bT6dLYGQRDfvKe",
        "category_id" : "5",
        "active" : "true",
        "category" : "Cognitive/Intelligence",
        "abbr" : "WISC-IV",
        "name" : "Wechsler Intelligence Scale for Children-Fourth Edition",
        "publisher" : "The Psychological Corporation"
    },

    {
        "_id" : "osAuaLrX97meRZuda",
        "category_id" : "7",
        "active" : "true",
        "category" : "Speech and Language",
        "abbr" : "WOJO",
        "name" : "Wechsler Intelligence",
        "publisher" : "The Psychological Corporation"
    },

    {
        "_id" : "57c62a784b94c533b656dba8",
        "category_id" : "5",
        "active" : "true",
        "category" : "Behavioral",
        "abbr" : "CARS",
        "name" : "CARS",
        "publisher" : "The Psychological Corporation"
    }
],
```

);
  },

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically loading all entries from "TestList" collection into "tests" array.

```
TestList = new Mongo.Collection('testList');
StudentSchema = new SimpleSchema({

tests: {
type: [Object],
blackbox: true,
optional: true,
autoValue: function () {
 return TestList.find().fetch();
},
```